# auto loader inferColumnTypes not working for dates

Tags: databricks, databricks-autoloader

I'm trying to understand why does setting this option as true works for numbers and booleans but not for dates. However, if I specify the data type as DATE using schemaHints then it does pick it up.

Dates have the following format: 2022-11-15T12:18:36

Comment: what is the input file format?

Comment: We're using json files